# Symfony 4.2.3 - Set ManyToOne Id when user register with email domain

Tags: symfony

[My page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afqZ1.png)

User entity :

```
<?php
s
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use App\Validator\Constraints as AssertPerso;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="app_user")
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne (targetEntity="Formation")
     */
    private $customerName;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return CustomerName
     */
    public function getCustomerName()
    {
        return $this->customerName;
    }

    public function setCustomerName($customerName): self
    {
        $this->customerName = $customerName;
        return $this;
    }


}
```

Formation entity :

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\FormationRepository")
 */
class Formation
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180, unique=true)
     */
    private $customerName;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return CustomerName
     */
    public function getCustomerName()
    {
        return $this->customerName;
    }

    public function setCustomerName($customerName): self
    {
        $this->customerName = $customerName;

        return $this;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->customerName;
    }

}
```

and my form UserType :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('customerName', null, array(
                'label'    => 'Client ',
                'required' => true)
        )
        ->add('submit', SubmitType::class, ['label_format' => "Register", 'attr'=>['class'=>'btn-primary btn-block']]);

    $builder->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
        array($this, 'preSetData')
    );
}

public function preSetData(FormEvent $event)
{

    $form = $event->getForm();
    $user = $event->getData();

         // $form->remove('customerName');


    $user->setEnabled(true);
}
```

In my database "formation", I have customer_name "xxx".

I want, when the user register, set the customer_name_id in my table "user" with the domain of the email if this email is like "xxxx" and if the domain of this email does not correspond with the customer_name, display error

Can you help me please ? Thank you

---

edit with Rebru response :

I succeeded to make the custom validator to check if the domain is an existing domain in "formation"

```
public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
{
    $mailParts = explode('@', $value);
    $mailParts = explode('.', $mailParts[1]);
    $domain = $mailParts[0];

            if(!$this->entityManager->getRepository(Formation::class)->findBy(array('customerName' => $domain))){
                $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->messageWrongDomain)
                    ->setParameter('{{ value }}', $this->formatValue($value))
                    ->setCode(Email::INVALID_FORMAT_ERROR)
                    ->addViolation();
                return;
            }
}
```

But now I do not know how to set the customer_name_id automatically when the user registers ?

### Thank you

Edit 2 :
I just tried that for set the customer_name_id in user table.

In my UserController :

```
$mailParts = explode('@', $user->getEmail());
            $mailParts = explode('.', $mailParts[1]);
            $domain = $mailParts[0];

            $customerNameId = $entityManager->getRepository(Formation::class)->findBy(array('customerName' => $domain));

            $customerNameId = $customerNameId[0]->getId();
```

I get the following error:

```
Expected value of type "App\Entity\Formation" for association field "App\Entity\User#$customerName", got "integer" instead.
```

Comment: You wanna only check against satcoms.fr?

Btw - i think your design is not optimal

Comment: Hello, no I will also check other domains that I add gradually. Can you put me on the right track? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, then your design is wrong - btw. i would suggest never use of manytomany over strings.

The right path to achieve this is to use custom validators ... like described here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html

Short:

- table with all customers ( id, name, formation_id)
- table with all formations ( id, name, domain )

In the custom validator, you can split the customers email ( explode("@", $email) ) and check this against the domains in the formation table. If it match, the validator should return true otherwise false. If the validator is true, you can save the customer.

With this approach the form will never be valid, until it matches the custom validator.

Comment: I edited my publication, I create the custom validator but now I do not know how to set the customer_name_id automatically when the user registers

Comment: Never persist with the integer (id) .. if its a relation you have to put the object into the set Command not the Id.

Like when you have your user and formation ...

$userObject->setFormation($formationObject);